# production issue: sqlite3 to postgresql migration issue in django

Tags: django, postgresql, production

I am trying to migrate my django project from sqlite3 to postgresql. I have done this succesfully in development but getting errors in production.

i have used this command to create dumps:

```
manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db.json
```

then i changed database in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

then i exclude contenttypes as follow:

```
python3 manage.py shell
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.all().delete()
quit()
```

but i am getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: insert or update on table 
"django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint 
"django_admin_log_content_type_id_c4bce8eb_fk_django_co"
DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id)=(7) is not present in table "django_content_type".
```

please help

Comment: You remove all `ContentTypes`... So `GenericForeignKey`s will no longer work, since the table is empty and you thus can no longer refer to a `ContentType`...

Comment: i try to remove using `ContentType.objects.all().delete()` but its still raising error, is there any other way?

Comment: of course, why do you want to remove the `ContentType`s in the first place?

Comment: @barkatpathan try to run this `ContentType.objects.clear_cache()`

Comment: in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907467/migration-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-django) he suggested to remove them but the error remains same just the key changed from 20 to 7

Comment: @AnkitTiwari thanx i tried this but still getting the same error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem even without removing those content types its not working. getting same error. `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_content_type_id_c4bce8eb_fk_django_co"
DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id)=(20) is not present in table "django_content_type".`

Comment: @barkatpathan: of course, since you need to add the values of the contenttypes to the database...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do you suggest is should do?

Comment: okay i have migrated succesfully. i have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

okay i figured out and migrated succesfully.
thanks to [ankit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14457833/ankit-tiwari), [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem)  and [Mostafa Ghadimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7310077/mostafa-ghadimi)

I followed Mostafa Ghadimi's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907467/migration-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-django) step by step.

also cleared cache suggested by[ankit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14457833/ankit-tiwari)